# Android event: Ring, vibrate and show alert box

Tags: android, alarm, schedule, android-vibration

I am trying to create an event in Android and when the time of the scedules event is reach, I want to display an alert box, ring and vibrate the phone. Can someone please help on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Handler class documentation

> Scheduling messages is accomplished with the post(Runnable),
>   postAtTime(Runnable, long), postDelayed(Runnable, long),
>   sendEmptyMessage(int), sendMessage(Message),
>   sendMessageAtTime(Message, long), and sendMessageDelayed(Message,
>   long) methods. The post versions allow you to enqueue Runnable objects
>   to be called by the message queue when they are received; the
>   sendMessage versions allow you to enqueue a Message object containing
>   a bundle of data that will be processed by the Handler's
>   handleMessage(Message) method (requiring that you implement a subclass
>   of Handler).

More information can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). In your case it seems that you need either `postAtTime` or `postDelayed`. The code would look something like

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //show alert, vibrate and ring..
    }
}, 10000);//execute this Runnable in 10 sec
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set an alarm using the AlarmManager.
Then you need a BroadcastReceiver to perform your tasks when the time is up.
To ring you would need to use the MediaPlayer using the URI of your preferred sound (notification / ringtone / alarm) and to vibrate you will be using the Vibrator service:
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

Now that you have the general idea I suggest you read some examples and the Android website for more details...